# how to get hierarchy signals with similar name?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

suppose in my test bench, i had following signals

```
top.module0.expect
top.module1.expect
```

yes, we instantiates module0/1 with same module
now, in a function *get_expect_sig*(int module_idx) (module_idx could be 0 or 1), i want to get the signal according to *module_idx*

what i'm currently do is as follow:

```
if (module_idx == 0) return top.module0.expect;
else if (module_idx == 1) return top.module1.expect;
```

this solution is pretty ugly.
if there any brilliant method that help me with this? because i got 32 modules, not 2 modules

thanks!

Comment: is `module_idx` a *varible*? a *parameter*?

Comment: module_idx is a variable, not a constant

Comment: then you cannot do much in this particular case. You can try to re-write your program and use `generate` `for` loops or virtual interfaces. It also possible to do a back-door access with quoted strings. if it worth it.

Answer (score 0):

A `case` statement would be slightly less ugly. Since your design choose to instantiate the modules with unique names instead of an array of instances, there is no way to iterate over them.

Some tools allow you to look up a signal's value using a string name. Then you could format the string using the index value. You'll need to read your tools manual.

Answer (score 0):

If this is testbench code (non-synthesizable), if module 0 and module 1 are instances of the same module, you could bind an interface to it. A bind statement will cause this interface to be instantiated in all instances of the module. You could then put some helper code in this interface to 'register' with a configuration class. In UVM, this could be the config db, but in SystemVerilog you could use a static or singleton class.

Example: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5ZUG

This uses a few concepts ([abstract-concrete polymorphic interfaces](http://verificationhorizons.verificationacademy.com/volume-7_issue-3/articles/stream/polymorphic-interfaces-an-alternative-for-systemverilog-interfaces_vh-v7-i3.pdf)) that you may need to read about. But hopefully the example is clear enough.

Comment: unfortunately module0/1 are instances of DUT which i shall not modify

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You don't have to modify anything.

Comment: module 0/1 are instances of DUT which i can't add interface binding code in the module

Comment: The bind statement occurs outside the DUT, in the testbench code. See chapter 23.11 of the Systemverilog 1800-2012 LRM.